# Proof for $A \cup B = B$ if and only if $A \subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to define a proof for

$A \cup B = B$ *if and only if* $A \subset B$

I started with:

$$A \cup B$$
$$x \in A \lor x \in B$$

but I am unsure on how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x \in A) \implies (x\in A\cup B=B)\implies (x\in B)\implies (A\subset B).$$ 
Conversely, Let $A\subset B$.
$$x\in A\cup B\implies (x\in B)\implies (A\cup B=B)$$

Comment: Could you explain me the first passage: $x \in A \cup B = B \Rightarrow x \in B$ ? Did you just assume that $x \in B$ given that $A \cup B = B$ ? Don't get me wrong, I understand the proof, but I don't know if it can be just as simple as it is.

Comment: @fbrundu If $x \in A \cup B$ and you know that $A \cup B = B$, then $x \in B$. It's a simple equality.

Comment: @Clarinetist yes, sorry for that. I'm learning proof writing and I was thinking that it needed a more complex passage. Thanks

Comment: $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B=B\Rightarrow x\in B\Rightarrow A\subset B$.

Comment: @Cla Sorry, I don't understand why $x \in A$ implies that $x \in A \cup B = B$ ?

Comment: $A\cup B=B$ by hypothesis and $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in A\cup B$ is the definition (you stated in your post).

Comment: @Clarinetist which is the passage from $x \in B$ to $A \subset B$?

Comment: @fbrundu If $x \in A$, $x \in A \cup B$, and since $A \cup B = B$, $x \in B$. Hence $A \subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

A U B implies x is in A or x exist in B . 
But since AUB=B , x exist in B .

That step is small but important in the explanation. 
I hope it helps

The fact that AUB=B is one of your givens. You use that statement to build your argument to show that ultimately A is a subset of B

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!
See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math on this site. What have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put some work into the problem.